# Undefined variable: posts (View: /home/.../annonces/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

hello l have problem I try to create search bar in laravel 5.8.

welcome.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($posts as $post)
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

PostController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\Poststore;
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $posts = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

        return view('welcome', compact('posts'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('posts.create');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'string'],
            'image' => ['required', 'image'],
            'price' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'descriptionpost' => ['required', 'string']
        ]);

        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("/storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
        $image->save();


        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'descriptionpost' => $data['descriptionpost'],
            'price' => $data['price'],
            'image' => $imagePath
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('profile.show', ['user' => auth()->user() ]);
    }

    public function show(Post $post)
    {
        return view('posts.show', compact('post'));
    }
}
```

route

```
Route::get('/welcome', 'PostController@index')->name('posts.index');
```

but i have this error :

> Undefined variable: posts (View:
>   /home/savinov/annonces/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

dont understand why its undefined variable if i define him in controller,
someone can helping to me if its possible?

Comment: have you checked, $posts have data or not in controller?

Comment: try `dd($posts)` in your controller to see what you're getting. You can also just pass it in as `return view('welcome', $posts);` seeing as you're only passing in one variable

Comment: dont work my friend ...

Comment: @DenKot What doesn't work? Can you be more specific? He asked you to do more than 1 thing. What's `dd($posts)` returning to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try like below options

**option 1**

```
public function index()
{
   $posts = DB::table('posts')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
   return view('welcome', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

**option2**

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    return view('welcome',compact('posts'));
     or 
   return view('welcome', ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

Comment: when i add option 1 its writing this Use of undefined constant posts - assumed 'posts' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Yeah, because it's `$posts`, not `posts`.

Comment: Also, @Hamelraj, althought you're giving him alternatives, your answer doesn't reply the question itself.

Comment: you are its the best )))))))